# Calculate Sum of Values from calculation done on MySQL Query Result in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have executed the following mysql query in python:

```
**convo_select_stmt =
"SELECT DISTINCT(AddressA) AS Source, SUM(Packets) As Total_Packets, SUM(Bytes) AS Total_Bytes, SUM(Duration) As Total_Duration FROM control_convo GROUP BY Source;"**
```

Next I used this code to display result of query:

```
**convo = connection.cursor()
convo.execute(convo_select_stmt)
result = convo.fetchall()**
```

Then I performed a calculation on the query result using this code:

```
**for row in result:
    #print(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])
    Total_Bytes = float(row[2])
    Total_Packets = float(row[1])
    Bytes_per_Packet = round(Total_Bytes/Total_Packets,2)**
```

When I print Bytes per Packet, I get the following result:

[Display Result- Bytes per Packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp3Ti.png)

Now, I want to calculate the sums of all the values displayed when I print Bytes per Packet.
However, I cannot use sum() or list() or even math.fsum()
I get the "float not iterable" error.

Edit:
Following comments below:
I tried:
(1)

```
Total_Bytes_per_Packet = sum(Bytes_per_Packet)
```

(2)

```
for i in range(int(Bytes_per_Packet)
    sum(Bytes_per_Packet)
```

(3)

```
nbpp_list= list(Bytes_per_Packet)
i=0
for i in nbpp_list[]
sum= nbpp_list[i] + nbpp_list[i+1]
i++
```

How would you proceed to calculate the sum of all values displayed in Bytes per Packet?

Comment: Please show what you actually tried, as opposed to a terse description.

Comment: Why not do the calculations in the query?

Comment: The value of Bytes_per_Packet was calculated from the result of the query : Total_Bytes and Total_Packets, by converting the row[i] as float. Then the float  Total_Bytes was divided by float Total_Packets... Please explain how this division can  be done by mysql query thanks Also calculations was done within for row in result, so a list of calculation for each row in table is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input.

I managed to do same my creating a list and appending the result of Bytes_per_Packet to the later.
The key was to declare the list as a global variable before the **for row in result** loop and to print the sum of the list outside the for loop:

```
global my_bpp_list
my_bpp_list = []
for row in result:
    Total_Bytes = float(row[2])
    Total_Packets = float(row[1])
    Bytes_per_Packet = round(Total_Bytes/Total_Packets,2)
    my_bpp_list.append(Bytes_per_Packet)

print(sum(my_bpp_list))
```